# Why some ajax calls not honoring server headers in response

Tags: dojo, xpages, lotus-domino

DISCLAIMER: perhaps wrong forum, might not be *coding* related…

If having a valuePicker on a Xpage like the following

```
<xe:djextListTextBox
    id="djextListTextBox1"
    value="#{requestScope.category}"
    multipleTrim="true"
    multipleSeparator=","
    >
</xe:djextListTextBox>
<xe:valuePicker
    id="valuePicker1"
    for="djextListTextBox1"
    dialogTitle="Category"
    dojoType="extlib.dijit.PickerCheckbox"
>
    <xe:this.dataProvider>
        <xe:simpleValuePicker
            valueList="red,green,blue"
            valueListSeparator=","
        >
        </xe:simpleValuePicker>
    </xe:this.dataProvider>
</xe:valuePicker>
```

The response header from the Ajax call is **NOT** honoring the http server headers set.

The reply:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 14 Feb 2018 10:21:01 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 73
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=604800; includeSubDomains
```

But another control on the same page using also an ajax call to the server honors the headers:

```
<xp:inputText
    id="inputText1"
    value="#{document1.subject}"
>
<xp:typeAhead
    mode="full"
    minChars="1"
    valueList="alpha#beta#charlie#delta#echo#foxtrot"
    valueListSeparator="#"
    tokens=",/"
    ignoreCase="true"
>
</xp:typeAhead>
</xp:inputText>
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 14 Feb 2018 10:34:36 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Expires: -1
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 48
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=604800; includeSubDomains
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 23:59:59 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store,private,must-revalidate
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

The server has defined several HTTP headers that we need to be honored thru all the system but for this **valuePicker** the response excludes them.

Why is that and how can this be fixed?

Using Domino 9.0.1FP10 on a Win/64 server and headers are defined as Web Site Rule and in notes.ini:

**Rule:**

```
HTTP response codes: 200, 206, 404, 403, 401, 500  
Always add header  
Specify a date: Expires after 1900-01-01
Header 1: Pragma, no-cache, override=true  
Header 2: Cache-Control, no-cache,no-store,private,must-revalidate, override=true  
Header 3: X-Frame-Options, DENY, override=true
```

**Notes.ini**

```
HTTPAdditionalRespHeader=Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' https://*.fontawesome.com https://code.jquery.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' https://*.fontawesome.com 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' https://*.fontawesome.com https://fonts.gstatic.com
```

Excluded the *HTTPAdditionalRespHeader* header from logs to make more readable…

Comment: How are headers defined on the server? That might explain why it's included for some areas not others.

Comment: Headers are defined in both as Web site rule HTTP response headers and in notes.ini för additional. This problem is only visible for a valuePicker afaik

Comment: I had to replace the Dojo controls with either a listbox or type-ahead for this… there's something really strange with these controls since they override the server's setting on headers… this is VERY BAD…